# Relative merits of Yubico OTP vs. OATH-HOTP?

Tags: multi-factor, one-time-password, yubikey

What are the pros and cons of using [Yubico OTP](https://developers.yubico.com/OTP/OTPs_Explained.html) vs. [OATH-HOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226)?  They both seem very similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Usability**

The Yubico AES mode does only work with a yubikey. The device returns a long data structure, that needs to be decrypted.

HOTP returns a 6 or 8 digit code. The algorithm uses a truncation to form the digit code. The digit code is created so that a user is able to read the code and type the code into a keyboard.

Thus: With Yubico AES mode you need to have a device that creates and inputs the one time password, while with HOTP you can always rely on the keyboard.

**Sync**

The Yubico AES mode increases two counters. A plug counter and a usage counter. This data is encrypted, then the encrypted value is sent for validation. Validation in this case means, that the encrypted value is decrypted and than the server verifies if the sent counters are bigger than the last counters, which the sever saw.

In HOTP mode the OTP value is calculated based on the counter. 
The server needs to perform the same operation like the OTP token.
This is why you have this window thing. The token could be pressed without the value being sent to the server. The server knows the last value (counter=n) it saw. But it does not know, how many blank presses were performed on the OTP token. So the server needs to //try// n+1, n+2...

The HOTP token can get "out of sync". The Yubico AES mode can not.

**Standards**

Yubico AES mode is well documented. But it is only implemented by the Yubikey.
HOTP is standardized in RFC 4226.

**Crytpography**

Well don't ask me. I suppose that both AES and HMAC-SHA1 are sill strong algorithms...

...now you can decide which aspect is a **pro** and which one a **cons**. Usually it boils down to usability and the question if you have a USB port or not.
The yubikey is one of the few hardware tokens, that can be initialized and thus you can keep control over your key material. Use a open source backend lile [privacyIDEA](http://privacyidea.org) to enroll and manage the tokens.

Comment: I actually think you missed one important difference: The key that is used. IIUC, the Yubikey OTP method uses a hardcoded symmetric (AES) key that is known by Yubico. Services using this method forward the generated OTP code to YubiCloud, which checks it and tells the service if it was ok. This means you can use unlimited services, since they all use the same key and delegate to Yubico.

With the OATH methods, the Yubikey and service agree on a shared key (configured through e.g. QR-code), which I would find more appealing (but is also limited to 32 keys/services with Yubikey 5).

Comment: @MatthijsKooijman The key for the AES mode is not hard coded, it is initialized, and thus YubiCloud knows it. You can very well initialize your own key for AES mode. This is what we can also do with privacyIDEA. Of course if you keep your Yubikey registered with the YubiCloud, you could use it with all services, that support the YubiCloud. 
So in my answer I did ignore the question, where the authenticating party (YubiCloud or on prem) is located because both is possible. And of course I personally would prefer on prem - but as you pointed out, some services will not support this...

Comment: Right, but even if you can replace the key used for the Yubikey OTP method, the significant difference is still that that method uses a *single* key, known by some party (yubicloud or your own server) that the services need to trust, while HOTP uses a unique key for each service, without requiring the service to trust any third party.

Comment: What? You can not use a unique Key with the Yubikey for different services. The yubikey as two slots. You can put two secret symmetric keys either for HOTP or for YubiOTP into it. No more. The "significat difference" does not exist - unless I completeyly do not understand, what you are trying to say.

Comment: Ah, I see. You are talking about the OTP mode, which has two slots which each can do Yubikey OTP, or OATH HOTP (or some others). I didn't realize that HOTP was also an option here, so I was talking about the OATH API method, which can store 30 credentials (but these need an app to access them, rather than a button and a keyboard emulator).

So indeed, when comparing the different OTP modes, I agree the difference I pointed out does not exist, it is only between OTP and OATH modes.

I couldn't quickly find the official docs, but this has good info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/YubiKey

Comment: Hm, actually, I guess the difference *does* exist, in that HOTP is *intended* to be used with unique keys, so the Yubikey supports only two HOTP services in its OTP mode, while Yubikey OTP with the preconfigured Yubicloud key is *intended* to support multiple services (that delegate their OTP checks to Yubicloud). In theory, HOTP could be used to delegate to a trusted third party as well, but I suspect that that is not actually specified or implemented by anyone.

Comment: Also, I think that Yubikey OTP might be slightly less safe when used with services you do not trust, since I think the OTP codes generated are not tied to a specific service, so service A could ask for an OTP code and then behind your back authenticate to *another* service you are using Yubicloud OTP for. But that's really another thing altogether, it's just that I realized it while writing the above. Couldn't quickly find any mention of this as a vulnerability, but I can't imagine I'm the first to realize this...

Comment: @MatthijsKooijman It is absolutely not about services here. I give a shit about any cloud services and do not use those. The originial post was solely about the technology aspect.